# To what extent is a vector bundle on a smooth manifold determined by its restriction to the complement of a closed smooth submanifold?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles

The question is a follow-up to [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/363360/to-what-extent-is-a-vector-bundle-on-a-manifold-with-boundary-determined-by-its).

- Let $N\subset M$ be a closed smooth submanifold of codimension $k\geq 1$ of a smooth manifold $M$. Let $E_1\rightarrow M$ and $E_2\rightarrow M$ be two vector bundles over $M$. Suppose $E_1|_{M-N}\sim E_2|_{M-N}$. Is it true that $E_1|_N\sim E_2|_N$?
- Can we impose some conditions on $k$ and $n=\dim M$ such that under the condition $E_1|_{M-N}\sim E_2|_{M-N}$, we can conclude $E_1\sim E_2$? (a counter example for this statement in general is provided by $E_1=T\mathbb{S}^1\rightarrow\mathbb{S}^1,E_2=\text{mobius}\rightarrow\mathbb{S}^1$ and $N=\{\cdot\}$) (the difference with the [previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/363360/to-what-extent-is-a-vector-bundle-on-a-manifold-with-boundary-determined-by-its) is that $M$ and $M-N$ are generally not homotopic).

Comment: The answer to the first question is No.  Just think of the inclusion of the circle in the 2-dimensional sphere.

Comment: @user43326: That doesn't work. Any vector bundle on $S^2$ is trivial on $S^2\setminus S^1 = D^2\sqcup D^2$ and on $S^1$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Thank you, yes, we need an example where the inclusion of N in M isn't null homotopic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example to show that the answer to the first question is no.

Let $M = \mathbb{CP}^2$ and $N = \mathbb{CP}^1$. Note that $M - N$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^2$ and is therefore contractible. So for any two vector bundles $E_1, E_2 \to \mathbb{CP}^2$ of the same rank, we have $E_1|_{M - N} \cong E_2|_{M-N}$. However, we need not have $E_1|_N \cong E_2|_N$. For example, if $E_1 = \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{CP}^2}(1)$ and $E_2 = \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{CP}^2}$, then $E_1|_N \cong \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{CP}^1}(1)$ and $E_2|_N \cong \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{CP}^1}$ which are distinguished by the second Stiefel-Whitney class.

Comment: Am I right to say that the real version with $\mathbb{RP}^2$ and $\mathbb{RP}^1$ also provides a counter-example in the case of real vector bundles?

Comment: @quangtu123: Yes. Although note that the counterexample I mention in my answer works for real and complex bundles: $E_1|_N$ and $E_2|_N$ are not isomorphic as real bundles and hence cannot be isomorphic as complex bundles either, although $E_1|_{M-N}$ and $E_2|_{M-N}$ are isomorphic as real bundles and as complex bundles.